# variables inside .env files are showing as undefined in other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, .env

This is defined in .env file:

`CHECK_INTERVAL=5`

The test-env.js file looks like:

```
require("dotenv").config()
console.log(process.env.CHECK_INTERVAL)
```

When running the file with:

```
node test-env.js
```

Result:

```
undefined
```

I have checked dotenv package is installed properly and .env file is in root directory of the project.
How can I access the variables in .env?

Comment: what does the folder structure look like? maybe .env file is in the wrong place?

Comment: The folder structure:
Main-Folder:
    src:
             test-env.js
    .env

Comment: After setup of env, app needs restart to get new env var

Comment: restarted multiple times.
Maybe the issue is due to AWS

Comment: is your issue on local or staging ?

Comment: You're saying you are using AWS. Is the .env present on your server? You may have a `.gitignore` file in your project preventing you to accidentaly push `.env` file.

Comment: I am running the app in local